# Can't call setState() after displaying CircularProgressIndicator()

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have the "standard" build code:

```
if (listOfLessons.length == 28)
  return MaterialApp(...);
else
  return MaterialApp(
        theme:  theme,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Getting Data from Belgium!'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          ),
        ),
      );
```

I have this in initState()

```
  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    _listOfLessons = lessonController.getLessons();

    setState(() {});
  }
```

getLessons

```
  List<Lesson> getLessons() {
    List<Lesson> listOfLessons = [];
    FirebaseLessonRepository lessonRepository = FirebaseLessonRepository();
    var flistOfLessons = lessonRepository.fbgetLessons();

    flistOfLessons.forEach((collectionSnapshot) {
      collectionSnapshot.docs.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
        FbLesson fbLesson = FbLesson.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
        List<DateTime> classOfferings = [];
        fbLesson.classOfferings!.forEach((fbClassOffering)  {
          classOfferings.add(
              DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                  fbClassOffering.seconds * 1000));
        });

        Lesson lesson = Lesson();
        lesson.lessonCode = fbLesson.lessonCode;
        lesson.prerequisite = fbLesson.prerequisite;
        lesson.description = fbLesson.description;
        lesson.online = fbLesson.online;
        lesson.sequence = fbLesson.sequence;
        lesson.classOfferings = classOfferings;
        listOfLessons.add(lesson);

      });
    });
    return listOfLessons;
  }
```

FirebaseLessonRepository

```
class FirebaseLessonRepository {
  static FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final CollectionReference _lessonCollection
    = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Lessons');

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> fbgetLessons() {
    return _lessonCollection.snapshots();
  }
}
```

From stepping through the debugger I see that in initState(),
_listOfLessons = lessonController.getLessons() returns before the query is finished loading the data, and then calls setState() right away.

I am not using Bloc or any other plugin other than firebase and dart:async;

My felling is that I should use a stream in getLessons() to trigger a setState();

something like this

```
class LessonsSpeaker {
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<List<Lesson>>();

  Stream<List<Lesson>> get stream {
    return _streamController.stream as Stream<List<Lesson>>;
  }

  speak(List<Lesson> listOfLessons) async {
    _streamController.add(listOfLessons);
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

But I am not sure how and where to invoke it.

Thanks for reading this long post.

Comment: if i may ask, why do you have multiple `MaterialApp`? How about moving it to top level on `main` function.

Comment: No reason other than I am new at this ;-)
I'll move it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Since calling `.snapshots` on the collection in Firebase returns a stream, i would suggest using a `StreamBuilder` (see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). The method in `initState` is not blocking (and it shouldn't be either) and thus the `setState` is called before the data is actually loaded

Comment: Made the change to Scaffold.

Reading up on StreamBuilder.... fingers crossed!